# Prevent creation of particular infotype records?

Tags: abap, badi, sap-hr

My aim is to protect users against of creation 105 infotype (communication) for some HR persons. I found **HRPAD00INFTY** BADI which called every time I save infotype updates. But the problem is that I cant prevent infotype creation/update from within **IN_UPDATE** method.

Does anybody know solution for the problem?

Comment: What happens when you throw an error like in CL_IM_HRFPM_CHANGE_LOG_CE~IN_UPDATE ?

Comment: Have you tried the after_input method?  That method has an exception you can raise.

Comment: @Bryan Cain: unfortunately such raise have no results

Comment: @tomdemuyt: yes, this solution is working, but it's too radical. I didn't expect transaction would be terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved with help of customer exits( http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Customer+Exits+%28CMOD%29 ) In our case we are using component **EXIT_SAPFP50M_002** of **PBAS0001** exit